# Add unique classes to divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to add to each div a new class but unique, how I can make this with jQuery?

```
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
```

[CodePen Project](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmoXed)

Comment: why unique class. try with `id` instead of class

Comment: Why? What is the problem/requirement you try to fix/accomplish?

Comment: i have 21 `div`s` and i want to add 21 `id` how i can do this with jquery or javascript?

Comment: just add in that html

Comment: I don`t like to repeat i want to learn short and productive solution to add to each an `id` unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`each()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjDue2B45TUAhUDrI8KHbCBAQQQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2FJQuery.each%2F&usg=AFQjCNE5AAT1VIjxq7NHT7kK5_TvLJ_VVg&sig2=ig2Knddjb31PAYVPvb702Q) and [`attr()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi50JT54pTUAhXHrY8KHfvsB14QFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fattr%2F&usg=AFQjCNE1qhpJI2G8J0vSJXrZ_Vf8dTKrTg&sig2=d7MyK3JINMu1CKsstVSYOQ) function of jquery .Better try `id` instead of `class` for unique

**For `unique`** `id` .

```js
$('.pat').each(function(a,b,c){
 $(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('class')+a)
})
console.log($('body').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you,this is solution i can`t accept your answer untill 7 minutes.have a nice day Guys!

Answer (score 1):

Quick, pure-js method:

```js
// for adding unique classes:
// var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.pat');
// [].forEach.call(divs,(el,i)=>{
//   el.classList.add('myclass_'+i)
// })

//for adding unique id's
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.pat');
[].forEach.call(divs,(el,i)=>{
  el.id = 'myId_'+i;
})
```

```html
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
<div class="pat"></div>
```

Comment: I think OP want id rather than class ! Check OP comment

Answer (score 0):

Include all div into wrapper.

```
 <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="pat"></div>
      <div class="pat"></div>
      <div class="pat"></div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#wrapper div").each(function(key){
     $(this).addClass("newclass"+ key);
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Why would OP need to move it into `wrapper`?

Comment: I just thought it would be a better idea to move it into wrapper div. Then there will be no dependency on inner div's class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
var divElements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
console.log(divElements.length);
var c=0;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(divElements,function(a) {
    a.classList = "div-" +c;
    c++;
    console.log(a);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("div").each(function(index) {
        
            $(this).addClass('pat'+index)
            
    });
});
```

```css
.pat0 {
  background-color: red;
}

.pat1 {
       background-color: blue;
}

.pat2 {

      background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pat">Pat0</div>
<div class="pat">Pat1</div>
<div class="pat">Pat2</div>
```